# Introduction in developing Cinnamon Shell Extension (Desklet) in CJS / GJS (Gnome JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs, cinnamon

I started learning how to write Cinnamon extensions. Well, I try to ... While I managed to write a first [simple desklet](https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/desklets/view/60), I still didn't find a really good and up to date documentation and introduction.

I have the following questions and would be very glad to get some hints:

**What is the best / suggested development workflow?**

For now, I do:

- copy the changed files from my project directory to `.local/share/cinnamon/uuid`,
- open Melange / Looking Glass,
- search there for the extension and reload it via right click
- switch to the Log tab and check for errors

Compared to vue.js development with [automatic hot-reload of changes](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/prototyping.html#vue-serve) in the browser, this seems a bit ... well ... time-consuming.

**Where do I find an introduction to the available widgets and widget libraries?**

I understood that there is Gtk and St and both have JS / GJS / CJS bindings.

The [Gnome Dev Docu](https://developer.gnome.org/documentation/introduction/overview/libraries.html) doesn't mention `St`. And I read in [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68277285/1480587) that it seems that shell extensions doesn't use `Gtk`, but rather `St` *instead* (and not in addition?).

I didn't find any documentation for `CJS` at all, but as far as I understood so far, it seems to be quite similar to `GJS`. Seems that the way desklets and applets are defined is different?

But now, I still would enjoy to have a (at least brief) introduction which widgets are available. While in [Gtk there seems to be a whole set of different list-like widgets](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/#classes), I didn't find *any* list widget in [St](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/st10%7E1.0_api/). And it seems that I can't use Gtk widgets as children of St widgets ...? This [St documentation](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/st10%7E1.0_api/) lacks any overview of available widgets and classes and what they can be used for.

**Documentation about events**

I found that there is the [St.Entry widget](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/st10%7E1.0_api/st.entry) that can be used for single-line text input. I found somewhere that I can bind functions to key press key release events like this:

```js
        this.input.connect('key-release-event', (widget, event) => {
            const input = widget.get_text();
            // ...
            return true; // event has been handled
        });
```

I didn't managed to get some information for the event.
When printing with `JSON.stringify(event)` It shows an empty object.

This [Gtk documentation](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk3/struct.EventKey.html) looks like there should be fields such as `keyval` and `state`, but these are undefined.

This is really kind of frustrating when it takes ages for every very small step to understand ... so, I would really appreciate any hints and suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I should note I have no idea what's been happening in CJS since it was split from GJS. Things have been moving pretty fast in GJS, so you may have to ask for help from the Cinnamon community if CJS hasn't been tracking upstream GJS.

The first place you should start is [gjs.guide](https://gjs.guide), which is the actively maintained portal for GJS and GNOME Shell extension documentation. There is also an [Architecture](https://gjs.guide/extensions/overview/architecture.html) page which briefly describes the relation of GNOME Shell extensions to the GNOME platform.

**Workflow**

There is a tiny snippet about how to test an extension by either restarting GNOME Shell or running a nested Shell, but it will need to be expanded at some point:

> To restart GNOME Shell in X11, pressing Alt+F2 to open the Run Dialog and enter `restart` (or just `r`).
>
> To run new extensions on Wayland you can run a nested gnome-shell using `dbus-run-session -- gnome-shell --nested --wayland`.

But again, I don't if the above will work with Cinnamon/CJS.

**Overview of Widgets**

Bindings for GJS are generated from introspection files, which are also used to generate the API documentation. In other words, our "GJS" version of the API documentation will only include material parsed from the C source. In the case of libraries like GLib, Gio, Gtk and so on, you can reference the [C documentation](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/#extra) for any other material and it should still make sense.

In the case of Clutter, I like to think of it as Gtk if the only widget was `GtkWidget`, with all of it's machinery. When it comes to `St`, almost every class is a direct analog of a Gtk widget, such as `GtkButton` and `StButton`. If you don't know what a class is for, chances are you can just glance at the Gtk documentation and you'll realize "Oh, `StIcon` is basically just `GtkImage`".

Mutter, on the other hand, there is no such high-level tutorials or overviews. It's best just to join Matrix or discourse.gnome.org and ask the community of extension developers and shell developers.

**Events**

With regard to `Clutter.KeyEvent`, I had actually forgotten how this situation was a little tricky and non-obvious. Put simply: "events" in this context are sort of polymorphic (I believe they're unions in C) which is why the generated API in GJS is a bit confusing. If you see [`Clutter.Event.get_key_symbol()`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/clutter8/clutter.event#method-get_key_symbol) and then browse around that page I think it will become clear and you should find all the accessors you need.

Here is the [list of key symbol constants](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/clutter8-constants/) and the [list of key symbol constans as C definitions in the source](https://github.com/GNOME/clutter/blob/master/clutter/clutter-keysyms.h) might be easier for searching.

Comment: Thanks for you very quick reply, I'll have a look

Comment: one question wrt to Clutter.KeyEvent: I did print `event.keyval` and it was undefined. Independent of the key I did press. Idea why? And: I like to check for pressing the Reutrn or Enter key. Best way to do this?

Comment: I did check the pages you linked. I remember that I did have a look at those before but I didn't find anything that answers my specific questions above.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot how this situation was tricky and non-obvious. I updated my above answer.

Comment: ah, `event.get_key_symbol()` works! :-) Where do I find documentation about the code returned? `get_key_code()` and `get_key_symbol()` both return a number. But https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/clutter8/clutter.event#method-get_key_code doesn't say details about what this number means and what the difference ist between the two.

Comment: to be more conrete: In my case I want to check for Enter& Return keys and also for modifiers. I guess there are some constants defined I should use ...?

Comment: It's unlikely you want a key code. `keysym` or key symbol is almost always what you want; it's the literal symbol you see on your keyboard keys. Those you can find in the ['(Constants)`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/clutter8-constants/) section in the sidebar for each library.

Comment: Great, it works :-) If you know what to do it's simple ... if I now want to test for Return-like-keys, are there more than these: `const keySymbol = event.get_key_symbol(); if (keySymbol === Clutter.KEY_Return || keySymbol === Clutter.KEY_KP_Enter) {`? In the list of constants there are also: `KEY_ISO_Enter`, `KEY_3270_Enter`, `KEY_RockerEnter` - is there documentation somewhere about these keys what they represent and what they should be used for? Or is there a way to test for anything that is Return-like in some meta-way?

Comment: And another thing: In the Gtk docs I found documentaton about different list widgets: https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/section-list-widget.html - but in St https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/st10%7E1.0_api/ there is no widget that reads (for me) like a list. Use `St.BoxLayout`? Or are there alternatives? In my case, it's a quite short list that will be updated and extended dynamically.

Comment: St predates GTK4, so it more closely resembles GTK3. You'll also find that there are fewer complex widgets in St, since it's much easier to build off the existing C toolkit and write them in JavaScript. You might want to look through the JS source of GNOME Shell for hints.

Answer (score 2):

I just found https://projects.linuxmint.com/reference/git/cinnamon-tutorials/ that also includes the Cinnamon-specific parts (but haven't looked into the details yet, I'll update :-))

I added some links to the referenced manuals below. For St I did not find an online version yet. But: you can install some dev documentation offline via `sudo apt install cinnamon-doc`. [This adds the Devhelp program in the Programming category of your menu and it has reference manuals for Cinnamon components and for libraries it uses.](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2013949)

> **Overview**
>
> The documentation of Cinnamon is separated into 4 different parts (5
> if you count muffin). What you are currently reading is the tutorials,
> which includes the general top-level overviews and tutorials you will
> need for Cinnamon. This is named “**[Cinnamon Tutorials](https://projects.linuxmint.com/reference/git/cinnamon-tutorials/)**”.
>
> The second part is the Javascript reference, which describes the
> Javascript part of Cinnamon. This is named the “**[Cinnamon Javascript
> Reference Manual](http://transit.iut2.upmf-grenoble.fr/doc/cinnamon/cinnamon-js/)**”. This is a technical reference for the individual
> functions and objects available in Cinnamon. Note that this
> documentation is aimed at both applet/extension developers and
> Cinnamon developers themselves. So depending on who you are, some of
> the information might be entirely irrelevant.
>
> The third part of the documentation is for the C part of Cinnamon,
> which is simply referred to as the “**[Cinnamon Reference Manual](http://transit.iut2.upmf-grenoble.fr/doc/cinnamon/cinnamon/)**”.
>
> The last part is the documentation for **[Shell toolkit, or St](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/tree/master/docs/reference/st)**. This is
> the graphical toolkit used to draw widgets on the screen (similar to
> Gtk).
>
> The modules covered by the Javascript documentation are those imported
> via imports.ui.* and imports.misc.*. The global object is documented
> in the C part of Cinnamon, as well as things accessed through
> imports.gi.Cinnamon. Things accessed through imports.gi.St are,
> unsurprisingly, documented in the St part.
>
> imports.gi.Meta refers to Muffin, while others (eg. imports.gi.Gio)
> are third-party (usually GNOME) libraries that are documented
> elsewhere.
>
> **Accessing the documentation**
>
> There are two ways of accessing this documentation, one of which is
> what you are currently using. The first method is accessing it online,
> which will be available at http://linuxmint.github.io.
>
> The second method is to *access it locally*. Install the program **devhelp**
> and the **cinnamon-doc** package (might be named differently in different
> distros or included in the cinnamon package itself). Then run the
> program devhelp to access all documentations you have installed in
> your system (not limited to Cinnamon).

And also worth a look might be the **[Linux Mint Developer Guide](https://linuxmint-developer-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)**

The [CJS repo in GitHub](https://github.com/linuxmint/cjs) includes also some [docs](https://github.com/linuxmint/cjs/blob/master/doc/Home.md) and [examples](https://github.com/linuxmint/cjs/tree/master/examples) (that are GJS apps in fact, but nevertheless a source of inspiration).

Comment: Thanks, that's a good help linking to that from here. FWIW, St doesn't change that much and is almost identical to its GTK counterparts. In other words, you can probably use our documentation for St and expect it to be accurate for Cinnamon.

Comment: I noticed that there are Cinnamon specific parts for the API for desklets, applets and so on. The rest seems to be quite identical from what I found so far.