# How to get a `St.BoxLayout` to 100% width in a Cinnamon applet (CJS / GJS)?

Tags: css, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs, clutter, cinnamon

I am writing my first Cinnamon applet (after I managed to write a desklet).

I have a `St.BoxLayout` embedded in a `PopupMenu.PopupBaseMenuItem` in order to get in in a popup menu.

Now I want it's width to be 100% of the popup menu width, but it (i.e. the box containing `1 +2 = 3` in the screenshot) looks like this and just takes its minimal width to contain the embedded text and it grows when you type into it:

[image: screenshot Cinnamon calc applet]

I tried:

- a style_class `expression-box` and in CSS `width: 100%`
- `x_align: Clutter.ActorAlign.FILL`,
- `x_expand: true`

But it just doesn't expand its width. What else could I try?

I must admit that I'm still looking for a [extensive CJS / GJS documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69312633/introduction-in-developing-cinnamon-shell-extension-desklet-in-cjs-gjs-gnom), browsing other applets' sources seem to be the best way to find out what is actually working ...

Here's the code:

`applet.js`:

```
        this.widgets.expressionItem = new PopupMenu.PopupBaseMenuItem({reactive: false, focusOnHover: true});
        this.menu.addMenuItem(this.widgets.expressionItem);
        this.widgets.expressionBox = new St.BoxLayout({
            style_class: "expression-box",
            vertical: true,
            x_align: Clutter.ActorAlign.FILL,
            x_expand: true
        })
```

`stylesheet.css`:

```
.expression-box {
    background-color: lightslategray;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

You can find the complete [source code in GitHub](https://github.com/ptandler/cinnamon-spices-applets/tree/7005b4ef8fb872f9e19e802f1532b1c1167012e0/calc%40ptandler/files/calc%40ptandler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS won't help you with layout in this case, as this is handled by the widget toolkit. While pixel widths like `width: 100px;` may work, percentages will not (unless something has changed quite recently).

It appears Cinnamon is using JavaScript wrappers around Clutter actors. The [function in current master](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/blob/239ee02ff89bc6b01e21f0169951fd10962e42bf/js/ui/popupMenu.js#L217-L229) looks like this:

```js
// adds an actor to the menu item; @params can contain %span
// (column span; defaults to 1, -1 means "all the remaining width", 0 means "no new column after this actor"),
// %expand (defaults to #false), and %align (defaults to
// #St.Align.START)
addActor(child, params) {
    params = Params.parse(params, { span: 1,
                                    expand: false,
                                    align: St.Align.START });
    params.actor = child;
    this._children.push(params);
    this._signals.connect(this.actor, 'destroy', this._removeChild.bind(this, child));
    this.actor.add_actor(child);
}
```

This was also the previous approach used in GNOME Shell, but [as you can see](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/blob/239ee02ff89bc6b01e21f0169951fd10962e42bf/js/ui/popupMenu.js#L352-L474) the allocation here gets pretty complicated. Since I don't use Cinnamon I can't test this myself, but I would assume that you need to add the child actor with the parameters desired like:

```js
this.widgets.expressionItem.addActor(this.widgets.expressionBox, {
    expand: true,
    span: -1,
});
```

It's unclear whether the child properties on `St.BoxLayout` will make a difference here, but you may have to play around with those a bit to get the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you so much, adding the `expand` to `addActor()` works! This is something I really would be able to solve myself ...

Comment: And: the child props in the BoxLayout are not necessary: `this.widgets.expressionBox = new St.BoxLayout({style_class: "expression-box", vertical: true })`